# merge/vlookup in R with many data frames/excel workbooks

Tags: r, excel, vlookup

I have 30+ excel workbooks that all have the same structure - Sheet 1(with the data), sheet 2 called "Metadata". I've already consolidated all of my data from all "Sheets 1" and now I'm trying to consolidate the information from Metadata and this has been proving very challenging for some reason. The metadata sheet is identical in all workbooks. It contains two columns and about 20 rows. The first column is identical as it describes the information that's then provided in column 2 - e.g. in column 1 I have name, source, time etc. and it's labeled "Dataset View Id". Column 2 has the corresponding values. I want to perform essentially a vlookup and create a summary table where each column lists information from each Metadata worksheet (i.e. values from column 2), and column 1 will be identical (i.e. name, source, time). I tried various alternatives of merge and reduce - base R and tidyverse, but it either takes forever to calculate and eventually returns an error that R reached its capacity or R crashes after a few minutes. Specifically, I tried the following:

```r
dataframe_list <- list(a, b, c, etc.) 
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), dataframe_list) #base R
```

or

```r
dataframe_list %>% reduce(full_join, by='Dataset View Id') #tidyverse
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to bind all rows with an identifier for every xls sheet then transform to wider data

Suppose you have data like that

```
dataframe_list <- list()
for (i in 1:5)
    dataframe_list[[i]] = data.frame(`Dataset View Id`=c("value1", "value2"), value = runif(2), check.names = F)

dataframe_list
#> [[1]]
#>   Dataset View Id     value
#> 1          value1 0.8541774
#> 2          value2 0.9110413
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Dataset View Id     value
#> 1          value1 0.6893812
#> 2          value2 0.2531087
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   Dataset View Id      value
#> 1          value1 0.07905447
#> 2          value2 0.68175406
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   Dataset View Id      value
#> 1          value1 0.27886536
#> 2          value2 0.02120348
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   Dataset View Id     value
#> 1          value1 0.3485775
#> 2          value2 0.5457035
```

you can add to every dataframe an id column. In the example Excel_id

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe_list <- purrr::imap(dataframe_list, ~ mutate(.x, Excel_id=.y))
```

Then, paste all together with bind_rows and finally do pivot_wider to get the desired result

```
result <- bind_rows(dataframe_list) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = `Dataset View Id`, names_from = Excel_id)
result
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   `Dataset View Id`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 value1            0.175 0.364 0.936 0.149 0.733
#> 2 value2            0.258 0.406 0.747 0.510 0.587
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>